# tf.keras 4x slower than Keras in my RL code

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, reinforcement-learning, tf.keras

I'm very new to Machine Learning.
I have found this example at Github: [Code](https://github.com/adventuresinML/adventures-in-ml-code/blob/master/r_learning_python.py)

I implemented the q_learning_keras function and chaned the Keras model to a tf.keras model.

With the Keras model 1000 Episodes take about 30 minutes.
With the tf.keras model 1000 Episodes take about 110 minutes.
Also the tf.keras variant need about 5-7% less cpu power.

I'm using Tensorflow version 1.13.1 and Keras version 2.2.4.
I'm runing the code on a virtual machine with 4 Cores @ 2.6 GHz.

Keras model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(batch_input_shape=(1, 5)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])
```

tf.keras model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(batch_input_shape=(1, 5)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='linear')
        ])
```

The rest of the code is in both excatly the same, ase in the Github example linked above.

In the most over post I have found exactly the opposite problem, that Keras was slower then tf.keras. So I also hoped to get an increase in speed or at least to stay the same.
So I think, I have maybe make a mistake but I don't find it.

Edit:
Done some more resarch, with Tensorboard to see how the model look like.
The models look very similar at the most things. But the tf.keras model have some overhead. I don't know if this is normal for tf.keras model or if it comes from my way I build the model.

[tf.keras model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwBgj.png)
[keras model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpBJ6.png)